# Change the value of textbox 1 base on the value of textbox 2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have table name lists on my database with 2 columns:

Ex.( lists has 50 row, below are just samples )

```
Name                 Type
Dog                  Animal 
Cat                  Animal
Apple                Fruit
Orange               Fruit
Eggplant            Vegetable
Carrot              Vegetable
```

Scenario : I entered a value on textbox 1 ( Something entered on textbox1 which is dog. ). Then after done on textbox 1, textbox 2 must change value to ( animal ). I'm having trouble formulating the answer.

TRY:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc(data){
    document.getElementById('outputValue').value = data;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#inputValue").blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
          url: "landing.php",
         data: {text:$('#inputValue').val()},
      success: myFunc
      });
    });
});

</script>

<input type="text" id="inputValue"><br/>
<input type="text" id="outputValue"><br/>
```

It's running. But when I'm trying my query there is no result. How can exactly find the dog row on db.

Note : `$search = Something entered on textbox1 which is dog`

```
$search= $_POST['text'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lists like name='%".$search."%'";
$res = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, it will be about 4 lines of Javascript.

Comment: Or use something like [dependent-dropdown](https://github.com/kartik-v/dependent-dropdown)

Comment: After writing on textbox1 catch the value (i.e Dog) of that textbox1 using onblur event of jquery. then send an ajax request to the server to fetch the row from the database. You will get the Type (i.e: Animal) for that ajax request on .success() callback. Now all you have to do is just push the type value to the textbox2 using plain javascript or jquery.

Comment: all are helpful. thanks. but is my query correct? or is it possible?

Comment: No, your query is invalid (you should have got an error message). Try  `$sql =  "SELECT * FROM lists WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'";` (BTW, no need of concatenation, since you used double quotes).